# Comparing negative values does not work properly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, comparison

I have the following code which changes the background color of a table data cell according to the numerical value inside the cell.
While all other comparisons work as expected, **(val<(-3000))** comparison never enters the block.
This is the code:

```
//Change Background Color for all P/L values
$(".PLcolors").each(function(index, value) {

  var val = Number(parseFloat($(this).text(), 10));

  console.log("value is " + val);

  if (val === 0) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#DCDCDC");
  } else if ((val => -3000) && (val <= 3000)) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#F0E68C");
  } else if (val < (-3000)) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#FF0000");
  } else if ((val > 3000)) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#008000");
  }
});
```

the type of val variable is number.

Comment: Please share fiddle for better clarity

Comment: What is the value of your `val` variable?

Comment: `parseFloat` takes only 1 argument. What gives you `console.log($(this).text())`?

Comment: @amoeba Sorry I cannot share a Fiddle since data are fetched live from a local webserver.

Comment: @Sergio The console gives back the value `-4282` exactly without any additional characters. The operation runs for multiple values so the format does not seem to be the main issue since for positive numbers > 3000 
the comparison and coloring is performed as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error inside your JS, you set `=>` instead of `>=`. Fix it to:

```
else if (val >= -3000 && val <= 3000) {
```

```js
//Change Background Color for all P/L values
$(".PLcolors").each(function(index, value) {

  var val = Number(parseFloat($(this).text(), 10));

  console.log("value is " + val);

  if (val === 0) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#DCDCDC");
  } else if (val >= -3000 && val <= 3000) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#F0E68C");
  } else if (val < -3000) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#FF0000");
  } else if ((val > 3000)) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#008000");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="PLcolors">1</li>
  <li class="PLcolors">-3001</li>
  <li class="PLcolors">3001</li>
  <li class="PLcolors">0</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh my god! Such a small typo! Thanks for pointing it out! Issue solved everything works as expected now!